# Place each element of a tuple inside another tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

```
Tuple1=('a','b','c')

Tuple2=(('a',),('b',),('c',))
```

I want to change tuple first Tuple1 as Tuple2.Is there a simply way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do :

```
tuple2 = tuple((t,) for t in tuple1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
tiple1=("1",'2','3')
new_tup=tuple(((val,) for val in tiple1))
print(new_tup)
```

Output:

```
(('1',), ('2',), ('3',))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Tuple2 = tuple([tuple(el) for el in Tuple1])
```

Comment: you don't need the inner `[]` - that creates a list object only to throw it away. Omit the `[]` and use a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

you can use, the `copy` module:

```
from copy import copy
Tuple2 = copy(Tuple1)
```